# is there a way to print the output to stdout and capture as well?

Tags: python

I am executing a command which takes around 15mins, I capture the output through `fetchPipe.communicate` and then print it. Is there a way in Python to print the output to stdout and capture as well?

```
    fetchPipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (output, error) = fetchPipe.communicate()
```

Comment: you already described how to?

Comment: Natecat - What I described is capturing to `output` variable,I want to print the output to stdout as the command runs and capture to `output` variable aswell,I want to do both

Answer (score 2):

Yes. An example for that could be using a listener function: Writing to stdout and triggering something upon line recieve

```
import sys
import subprocess
import threading
```

The listener

```
def listener(proc):
     for line in proc.stdout:
         sys.stdout.write(line)
         triggerRecvLine(line)
     proc.wait()
```

It might be wise to run the listener in a different thread.

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
t = threading.Thread(target=listener, args=(proc, ))
t.start()
```

Comment: You can simply call the function without a thread. Though it will block the parent process

Comment: ` global name 'triggerRecvLine' is not defined`

Comment: triggerRecvLine is just a placeholder for you to insert your code. At that point you have already printed it out and can access the child process' stdout